# angularjs provider injector.get

Tags: angularjs, provider

Is there a way to get provider instance / object at run time using string? I can get factory that way using:

```
var injector  = angular.injector(["myApp", 'ng']);
var keyf1 = injector.get('keyF1');  //-- providing it exists
```

but if done for provider, `injector.get` seems to return new instance of provider; that causes issue as there is statefull data in provider, so new instance is not what I need - I need access to current instance using string name.

My guess is that it could be worked around by putting statefull data into config part of provider, but I am not sure that is the best approach here .

Answer (score 0):

Providers are used to configure factories in config time, before Angular.js application starts running. We should use them to configure how factories are going to behave in runtime. So, I think you need to do some hack to access a provider on runtime.

You may try to change your approach. You may put your stateful data to a factory. I can try to do a better comment, if you can give a concrete example.

Also, this is a good comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15666049/158523

Comment: Yes that is an option - I use factories for few things in the code - but was hoping to keep providers in cases where config part provides flexibility I don't get from factories and I might need. But yes, that is another option - get away from provider, or dynamic referencing using name.

Comment: .. it is just interesting that one can get reference to factory instance at run time but not to providers.